# Angularjs How to import controller on the view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator

i'm making a big project with over 50 controllers, is there a way to call each controller independently once it is on its view? i don't want the user to load all the controllers at once. as you can see below all the controllers will be called no matter where i am on my site.

```
<!doctype html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <base href="/">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->
    <!-- build:css(app) styles/vendor.css -->
    <!-- bower:css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->
    <!-- build:css({.tmp,app}) styles/main.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
    <!-- endbuild -->
  </head>
  <body ng-app="nodeserverApp">

    <!-- Add your site or application content here -->
    <div class="container" ng-view=""></div>
    enter code here

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="bower_components/es5-shim/es5-shim.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/json3/lib/json3.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- build:js(app) scripts/vendor.js -->
    <!-- bower:js -->
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->

        <!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
        <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/navbar.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/login.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/signup.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/settings.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/services/auth.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/services/session.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/services/user.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/directives/mongooseError.js"></script>
        <!-- endbuild -->
</body>
</html>
```

When i try to move the script tag to the view, angular does not detect that controller and sends an error.

Comment: I haven't implemented it, but here is an article on [Lazy Loading Controllers in AngularJS](http://ify.io/lazy-loading-in-angularjs/)

Answer (score 0):

Your controllers should look something like this:

```
angular.module('app')
  .controller('HomeCtrl', function () { /* ... */ });
```

So, they won't be called, as in "invoked". They'll just be registered under your module.

When you configure your `app.js` file, or wherever your module is declared for the first time (when you list its dependencies), that's when you'll connect routes to controllers:

```
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute'])
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
      controller: 'HomeCtrl',
      template: '<p>hi!</p>',
    });
  });
```

Everything you pass in as a function to `angular.module('app').__whatever__` is going to be internalized and used only when it's needed. So, you don't need to worry about including the scripts and worrying about your controllers being invoked before your route is active.

Hope I understood correctly, and this is helpful.

Comment: I understand, but still the browser itself will download all the scripts at once consuming unnecessary bandwidth from the client.

Comment: I feel I just have suggestions that would be better suited for a small-scale application, so I will let others guide you on topics such as lazy-loading.

However, if any of those smaller scale app developers might see this, your build task should concatenate and minify your application source files. All combined, they shouldn't carry much weight, and if you're not yet worried about scaling to infinite growth, this will suffice for you and your users.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you use some CMS for your backend web site, but in my case I use Drupal for the base of my site. With Drupal for every single page that users request I can set which JS files need to be loaded (via writed them into  HTML file). Ok, in this way I can not use Angular route/view but in my case it is ok because part of the html template work is done by Drupal. However Sthephen have rigth when he talks about concatenate and minify your application source files. This reduce bandwidth and number of files that the user request for single page.